# How to know user is dragging something when the cursor is not in my window?

Tags: windows, delphi

We all know you can implement drag-and-drop feature for your Window so that it accepts drag and drop operation, but my question is, how to detect a drag-and-drop operation that's is in progress **in other windows**, for example, dragging a file in the Windows Explorer? What I want to do is that when a user is dragging a file then my hidden window shows up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not natively supported.  During a drag&drop operation, only the originator of the drag knows the operation is in progress, and only windows actually being dragged over get notifed that the operation may occur on them.

The only option I can think of right now is to implement a global mouse hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` in a DLL and have it keep track of when the user holds down the left button and moves the mouse outside of the source window.  But there is no way to get information about what is being dragged.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for the help. It's sad to know that "there is no way to get information about what is being dragged". And since the Delphi DLL's does not work under 64bit windows, maybe it'll better to have a background program to periodically check the left mouse button state?

Comment: Doing periodic checks can easily get out of sync with the user's actual actions, especially if the user does quick drags and small motions.  Hooks are real-time and detailed, but there are no hooks for intercepting COM-based drag&drop operations.  If a given target window uses DragAcceptFiles() instead of RegisterDragDrop(), then you can intercept WM_DROPFILES messages that are sent to it, but that is an old-style approach to drag&drop.  Most apps support the IDragSource and IDropTarget interfaces nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the further comment, Remy!

Answer (score 0):

When most of Drag&Drop operations start, system creates a feedback window with "SysDragImage" class. It's possible to catch the creation and destruction of this feedback window, and react in your application accordingly.

Here's a sample code (form class declaration is skipped to make it shorter):

```
procedure WinEventProc(hWinEventHook: THandle; event: DWORD;
  hwnd: HWND; idObject, idChild: Longint; idEventThread, dwmsEventTime: DWORD); stdcall;
var
  ClassName: string;
begin
  SetLength(ClassName, 255);
  SetLength(ClassName, GetClassName(hWnd, pchar(ClassName), 255));

  if pchar(ClassName) = 'SysDragImage' then
  begin
    if event = EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE then
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Drag Start')
    else
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Drag End');    
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FEvent1 := SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, 0, @WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
  FEvent2 := SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, 0, @WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnhookWinEvent(FEvent1);
  UnhookWinEvent(FEvent2);
end;
```

The only issue here is when you press Escape right after beginning of the Drag & Drop, the system won't generate EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY event. But this can easily be solved by starting timer on EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, and periodically monitoing if the feedback windows is still alive.

Answer (score -1):

I use DropMaster from Raize Software.
http://www.raize.com/devtools/Products.asp

You can also use from Melander, but i didn't test this one. 
http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/.

Comment: HI Ravaut, I'm a paid customer of DropMaster, I'm also using the drag and drop component suite from Melander, but they are for implementing standard drag-N-drop operations which means your windows won't get notified until the mouse cursor is dragging over your form, and this is not what I'm asking in this topic. Thanks.